# Want to get a grip of this pyautogui command

Tags: python, location, pyautogui

Well, I pretty much just copied this code that gets the `x` and `y` position of the cursor, and 'I'd like to ask what each line of command does so I can get a grip of it.

Thanks in advance !

```
print('Type Ctrl-C to stop the program')


try:
    while True:
        x, y = pg.position() 
        coordinates = 'X: ' + str(x).ljust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).ljust(4)


        print(coordinates, end='')
        print('\b' * len(coordinates), end='', flush = True)

except KeyboardInterrupt():
    print('\n See you next time!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a while loop which will never end  as `True` is universal truth.

After that  you have used `pg.position()` to get the live cursor position which will give you the x and and y coordinate of the cursor on the screen in two tuples defined here x and y. You can get your screen size with `pg.size()`

Then you are defining a variable named `coordinates` where you are using `ljust()` method that returns the left-justified string within the given minimum width.
`str.ljust(width[, fillchar])`
If fillchar is defined, it also fills the remaining space with the defined character.

In next line you have printed the coordinates and again printing length of coordinates with `flush()` method whose only work is to flush the internal buffer. `\b` is used to backspace one character before it.

And in the last you are using `KeyboardInterrupt()` which is raised when you try to stop a running program by pressing ctrl+c or ctrl+z in a command line .
This is a summary but to get grip I recommend to see the whole documentation.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Now i got the reputation limit to comment on replies, and wanted to say thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Congrats for that @lowy2low :)